# creating vertical arrays of in python, can I avoid the reshape function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I want to create a vertical array according to the following

```
import numpy as np

L = 2**15
dx = 0.1
x = np.arange(-L/2,L/2)*dx
x=x.reshape((L,1))
```

This creates an array of dimension L,1 which is fine but is there a cleaner way to do this? I feel my solution is clunky

Comment: Where is `N` defined?

Comment: Sorry, N should be L. edited

Comment: What's wrong with reshape? You can also chain the commands: `x = np.arange(-L/2,L/2).reshape(-1,1) * dx`.

Comment: Reposting a question just because you aren't satisfied with the answers you got is not considered good SO behavior.  Comment on the answer you were given if necessary.  If you must build on something earlier, at least acknowledge the previous answers.

Comment: It's not an explicit repost. I'm asking how to streamline something I did previously. I didn't realise this contradicts SO policies and won't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
x = (np.arange(-L/2,L/2)*dx)[:, None]
```

Or:

```
X = L*dx/2
np.arange(-X,X,dx)[:, None]
```

Though you might accumulate errors with the second approach due to floating point calculations.